# Is there an alternative to Google Maps to calculate distances when using a bicycle or public transport?

Tags: google-maps

I'm creating a website using Google Maps API and everything was fine until the client asked me if it was possible to calculate distance and travelling time when riding a bicycle or when using public transport. As far as I know, GMaps support bicycle in the US only and has no support for public transport.

I need a solution that is available world-wide. What other options do I have apart from Google Maps? Can I use web services from other sites and then combine them with GMaps API? (for example make a query to public transport companies and then display the result on GMaps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out this option that looks promising:

http://developer.mapquest.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Maps API (GMaps) and simple distance calculations to calculate cycling distances throughout the world.  An example website which calculates distances on google maps using Google Maps API and javascript is http://www.mappedometer.com/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use device's GPS to get the coordinates? GPS can get you distance, time, speed, altitude, bearing. Also you can plot the coordinates you got from GPS to Google Maps.

Comment: No, the user needs to plot is path from the PC to use later, so i need to be able to calculate the distances between different point of intersts giving the user the option to choose  what to use (bycicle, public transportation, walking, car)